# How to log actions in AWS Lambda and download them from a mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my AWS project, I created webservices using API Gateway, Lambda, DynamoDB and S3, that are called by an Android app.

Now, I want to log specific actions on my webservices (in my lambda functions), so I can download them from an Android app.

Here is what I was thinking of:

- append my logs to a text file (or multiple text files) in S3, but then I have to download the file, append the logs, then upload the file, each time I need to add a log (doesn't sound very optimized)
- store my logs in a DynamoDB table, but it doesn't look like a clean solution, and might be pricy
- using CloudWatch Logs to log everything I want, but then I need to only extract the logs I need, and it seems quite complex, and not sure it's the best solution either

So what is the most suitable solution to log actions in lambda functions, so I can then download them from an app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use AWS Kinesis Stream if you want to analyze your logs on the fly, or use Kinesis Firehose if you just want to aggregate your logs and store them in the same place.

Kinesis Firehose can receive logs from multiple sources, aggregate your logs and save it in S3. When the log is saved in S3, you can use AWS Athena to do queries in these logs files. To connect it with an Android Device to download the logs, you can build an API to communicate with Athena.

And if you to personalize the view for each Android Device, just make sure to include a unique ID in each log and query for this ID in Athena.